# Change Image on Correct Password

Tags: android, string, passwords, android-imageview, android-edittext

So I am a complete newb, and am currently taking an intro to Mobile Programming course in which we use Android (I have some experience with Java).  I am trying to do a simple assignment which displays a text field and an image, and upon entering the correct "password" and pressing enter, the image changes.

Should be so simple! But I am having a really hard time with this and can't figure out what I am doing wrong, even after doing a good bit of searching (I assume it is something super obvious and I'm missing it).

Here is my code:

```
package CS285.Assignment1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DisplayImage extends Activity 
      implements OnKeyListener{

 private EditText enteredText;
 private String pass = "monkey";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        enteredText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passField);
        enteredText.setOnKeyListener(this);    

    }

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
          // Perform action on key press

         switchImage();

          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void switchImage(){

  if(enteredText.getText().toString() == pass){
   ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Image);
         imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.marmoset);
  }     
    }

}
```

and my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textPrompt" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:background="#ff993300" 
  android:text="Please enter password to see my real picture:" 
 >
 </TextView>
 <EditText android:id="@+id/passField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        </EditText>
<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/Image"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
 android:src="@drawable/airplane"
/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I thought at first that I was not properly extracting the String from "enteredText" so the comparison to the "password" wasn't happening correctly, but I have since tried just printing the enteredText and it works fine.

Totally frustrated--Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(enteredText.getText().toString() == pass)` should be `if(enteredText.getText().toString().equals(pass))`.

As a stylistic matter, you should not do the checking within the switch image function - you should check that the password matches and *then* call the switch image function.

Comment: Thank you so much, I82Much! I hope some day I will be able to pay it forward for another wayward programmer...!

Comment: If that worked for you please press the checkbox to the left of the answer :)

Comment: You did indeed, a nice round number to have.  Though I liked when I was at 1337 for a few days..